# Keras / Tensorflow: optimise learning for better sensitivity & specificity?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

Currently I've been learning like so:

```py
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          shuffle='batch',
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=callbacks)
```

With these metrics being output every epoch so I know how well it's performing:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predictions = model.predict(x_test)
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1)
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
c = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
print('Confusion matrix:\n', c)
print('sensitivity', c[0, 0] / (c[0, 1] + c[0, 0]))
print('specificity', c[1, 1] / (c[1, 1] + c[1, 0]))
```

Depending on my architecture, I get better results at epoch 93 or 155; then it gets worse. So clearly my `metrics` are wrong.

**How do I learn from the sensitivity and specificity results each epoch?**

Answer (score 0):

To learn from the sensitivity and specificity results, you could write a custom loss function where the loss is computed depending on your confusion matrix results. Alternatively, you could try the `class_weight` parameter in keras [model.fit()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) and assign different weights to classes depending on which ones your model finds harder to learn.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, that's what I should be doing. Could you include a code example? - It is neither clear what dictionary to generate for `class_weight` nor how to go from `(y_true, y_pred)` to `(predictions, y_test)`. Was it just `(np.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), model.predict(y_pred))`?